# eclipse shiro ini problem

Tags: eclipse, security, google-app-engine, shiro

Honestly, before posting question did googling and 2 days tried to solve problem on my own...

I want to get Apache Shiro working with GAE. Before that, I had success with Spring Security, but here I can't do a simple thing: to get the filter find my shiro.ini !

After introducing ShiroFilter in web.xml, in init-param tag I give a value of classpath:shiro.ini for the param-name called configPath, as standard way.

Next, I put shiro.ini in my src root, won't work, then under /web-inf/shiro.ini, again didn't work...

any help please?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "didn't work" before anyone can help you. What happens? Do you get an exception? If so, include the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.gdevelop.com/blog/2010/12/apache-shiro-on-appengine/) tutorial of integrtating Shiro with GAE will be useful?